# Using Datastax Cassandra Driver from Scala

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I wanted to explore using the Datastax Cassandra CQL3 driver from scala but think I may have fallen at the first hurdle.

In methods for creating a Cluster  object in [the Javadoc](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/apidocs/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html) there is an overloaded method for `addContactPoints` which take either a sequence of String or a Sequence of java.net.InetAddress as parameters.
Is there a way of modelling this in an idiomatic Scala way so I can try and pattern match on the type and arity of an input parameter to call the correct method.

with

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

def cp = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint _

def cps = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints _
```

cp returns

```
cp: String => com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder
```

cps however gives

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,

both method addContactPoints in class Builder of type (x$1: <repeated...>[java.net.InetAddress])com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder

and  method addContactPoints in class Builder of type (x$1: <repeated...>[String])com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder
match expected type ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about explicitly specifying the type of the function?

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster

def cp = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint _
def cps(addresses: [String]) : Cluster.Builder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(addresses)
```

Comment: Nearly there -  I ended up with  def cps(addresses: Seq[String]): Cluster.Builder = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(addresses:_*)